# Insert a row to table with many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have client on JS and backend on ASP.NET with EF Core. Client sends backend an object, which contains another objects. Users object in group object.

[payload object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7YfQ.png)

My app implies, that all users, which client can send to backend, already exist. Client is trying to create a group and add to this group of existing users.

[DB diagram, where AspNetUsers table is Users class in ASP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMvE3.png)

And when I add it to the database, I get problem with primary key: EF Core is trying to add those rows to all 3 tables:

> SqlException: The PK_AspNetUsers PRIMARY KEY constraint was violated. Failed to insert duplicate key into object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'. Duplicate switch value:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [AspNetUsers] ([Id], [AccessFailedCount], [ConcurrencyStamp], [Email], [EmailConfirmed], [LockoutEnabled], [LockoutEnd], [NormalizedEmail], [NormalizedUserName], [PasswordHash], [PhoneNumber], [PhoneNumberConfirmed], [SecurityStamp], [TwoFactorEnabled], [UserName])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14),
(@p15, @p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29);

INSERT INTO [Groups] ([Id], [Name], [UserId])
VALUES (@p30, @p31, @p32);

INSERT INTO [UserGroups] ([GroupsId], [UsersId])
VALUES (@p33, @p34),
       (@p35, @p36);
```

User class:

```
public partial class User : IdentityUser 
{
    public ICollection<Group> JoinedGroups { get; set; } // navigation property to UserGroups table
    public ICollection<Group> CreatedGroups { get; set; } // navigation property to Groups table
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; } 
}
```

Group class:

```
public partial class Group
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User? User { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; } = new();
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; } = new List<Event>();
}
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
.HasMany(e => e.Users)
.WithMany(e => e.JoinedGroups)
.UsingEntity(
    "UserGroups",
    l => l.HasOne(typeof(User)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("UsersId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(User.Id)),
    r => r.HasOne(typeof(Group)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("GroupsId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Group.Id)),
    j => j.HasKey("UsersId", "GroupsId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
.HasMany(e => e.Events)
.WithOne(e => e.User)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
.IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
.HasMany(e => e.CreatedGroups)
.WithOne(e => e.User)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
.OnDelete(deleteBehavior: DeleteBehavior.NoAction) 
.IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
.HasMany(e => e.Events)
.WithOne(e => e.Group)
.HasForeignKey(e => e.GroupIdentificator);
```

Code to add to database:

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse> CreateGroupAsync(GroupDTO groupModel, string authUserId)
{
    if (authUserId == null)
        return ServiceResponse.Fail("You are not authenticated!");

    try
    {
        groupModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var obj = _mapper.Map<Group>(groupModel);
        _webDiaryContext.Groups.Add(obj);
        await _webDiaryContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // error appears here

        return ServiceResponse.Success("Group successfully created!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ServiceResponse.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

When I am adding users to group entity not from client, but in backend, it works (here I'm adding also the "Unchanged" state to users entity):

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse> CreateGroupAsync(GroupDTO groupModel, string authUserId)
{
    if (authUserId == null)
        return ServiceResponse.Fail("You are not authenticated!");

    var test = _webDiaryContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.UserName == "test3@mail.ru");
    _webDiaryContext.Entry(test).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    try
    {
        groupModel.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var obj = _mapper.Map<Group>(groupModel);
        obj.Users.Add(test);
        _webDiaryContext.Groups.Add(obj);
        await _webDiaryContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return ServiceResponse.Success("Group successfully created!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ServiceResponse.Fail(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And EF Core generates the correct code with only two tables:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [Groups] ([Id], [Name], [UserId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);

INSERT INTO [UserGroups] ([GroupsId], [UsersId])
VALUES (@p3, @p4);
```

And it is ok, really I can get users from database again and add it to database this way, but I don't want to do it. I have already fully receive users from client, this users is not changed in client and sends them to back in the same form.

I think I should made this user navigate property in group entity is "Unchanged" state. How can I do this in my code?

Comment: Do you call `base(modelBuilder)`?

Comment: yes, 

`code`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);`code`

in protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in context